# Database of Android APK checksums

Tags: data-request, software

Android APKs are often restricted by regions, for instance an APK is available in Korea but not in Nigeria, for obscure marketing and narrow-mindedness reasons. That leads many Android users to download APKs from a wide range of **dodgy APK download sites**.

- Problem: Intducing spyware/malware in an APK is easy, and many of these download sites do it.
- Solution: **Verify the checksum of the downloaded APK**. Unlike APK themselves, checksums are legal to publish.

**Request**: I am looking for a database of checksums of APK files.

Requirements:

- Checksums of most popular apps present on Google's Play Store
- For as many versions as possible of each app, at least the most recent version (some lag is acceptable)
- Using any popular secure checksum algorithm such as SHA1
- Searchable by application name or namespace